# How do I create a Google Drive folder with only a path name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How do I create a folder in Google Drive from only a pathname? Preferably I need the code to not fail if either the folder or any of it's sub-folders already exist.

In the script I'm working in I only have the path name to a folder that I need to create in Google Drive:

```
newFolder = '/Path/To My/New Folder/';
```

If I use the following code:

```
DocsList.createFolder(newFolder);
```

It will create a folder at the root level called **"/Path/To My/New Folder/"**

My understanding is the correct syntax would be:

```
DocsList.createFolder('Path').createFolder('To My').createFolder('New Folder');
```

However if I only know the path, do not know how many sub-folders the path could contain, and do not know which of the folders/ sub folders exist what code should I use to create the folder from only a path?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function createFolderFromPathName(newFolder){
  var paths = newFolder.split("/");
  var curPath = "";
  var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders();
  var curFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folder;

  for(path in paths){
    var hasFolder = false;

    while(!hasFolder && folders.hasNext()){
      folder = folders.next();
      if(paths[path] == folder.getName()){
        hasFolder = true;
      } 

      if(hasFolder){
        folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(DocsList.getFolder(curPath+paths[path]).getId()).getFolders();
        curPath = curPath == "" ? paths[path] + "/" : curPath + paths[path] + "/"; 
        curFolder = DocsList.getFolder(curPath);
      } 
    } 

    if(!hasFolder){
      curFolder = curFolder.createFolder(paths[path]);
    } 
  }  
 return curFolder;
}

function test(){
 createFolderFromPathName("Folder/Design/Test"); 
}
```

Thanks Serge, I figured something like it would be useful later on. I might end up creating a Folder/File library that does tasks similar to these when creating larger scale file/folder architectures.

Answer (score 4):

A far more compact, less error-prone way to find or create a folder:

```
function createFolderFromPathName(fullPathToFolder) {
  var paths = fullPathToFolder.split("/");
  var curFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var folders = curFolder.getFoldersByName(paths[i]);
    curFolder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : curFolder.createFolder(paths[i]);
  }  
  return curFolder;
}
```

Comment: DocsList is deprecated, so this is a much better solution now.

Answer (score 0):

**This is only a comment on the other answer (user1475265), written here for format convenience**

this code can be improved (a bit) by returning the folder object from the function so it can be used directly to create a document... test and (very little ) modification below :

```
function createFolderFromPathName(newFolder){
  var paths = newFolder.split("/");
  var curPath = "";
  var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders();
  var curFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folder, folderName;

  for(path in paths){
    var hasFolder = false;

    while(!hasFolder && folders.hasNext()){
      folder = folders.next();
      folderName = folder.getName();
      if(paths[path] == folder.getName()){
        hasFolder = true;
      } 

      if(hasFolder){
        folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(DocsList.getFolder(curPath+paths[path]).getId()).getFolders();
        curPath = curPath == "" ? paths[path] + "/" : curPath + paths[path] + "/"; 
        curFolder = DocsList.getFolder(curPath);
      } 
    } 

    if(!hasFolder){
      curFolder = curFolder.createFolder(paths[path]);
    } 
  }  
  return curFolder;// by returning the folder object it can be used directly, see test function
}

function test(){
  var curFolder = createFolderFromPathName("Folder/Design/Test"); 
  var emptyTestDoc = curFolder.createFile('testDoc','empty');// creates an empty text document
}
```